# Add to Cart and other WooCommerce form links only use http actions and don't work on https website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been setting up a WooCommerce store on an existing website and I have been having a problem where the Add to Cart button's form sends the user to a URL that begins with http, which gives an error in most major web browsers and is not processed by the server. The same occurs if you try to update any of the cart's settings, such as the address and the quantity of product in the cart.

I have tried the following:

- changing the website URLs in the wp_options table in the database
- using SSL plugins such as Really Simple SSL, which doesn't solve the problem
- reinstalling the SSL certificate to force HTTP to HTTPS redirect
- using WooCommerce's Force SSL setting to force HTTPS
- overwriting the default cart templates, which does not work since the form action URLs are generated by PHP

I'm not sure what else to do to solve this. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can i have the URL of the store please?

Comment: Just curious to know that why your are changing in wp_options table in DB ? when you can easily do that in WordPress  setting page ?

Comment: @RajaGopal the URL is https://aircraftbuyer.net, although purchasable products are currently private since the store has not been launched yet. In answer to your 2nd question, it doesn’t allow me to change the URL in the WordPress settings, despite having full admin permissions. I checked in the wp_options database and the URLs both began with https.

Comment: When u try to change in WordPress settings in dashboard what error message comes?. Let me know.

Comment: @RajaGopal There is no error message, the two text fields are disabled, as shown here: https://calumchilds.com/imgs/Capture.PNG and when you enable them, change the setting and press "Save changes", it says that it has saved successfully but it hasn't changed the functionality of the website.

Comment: Given answer below. Try and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few troubleshooting options to be followed :

Check whether you have changed the URL to **https** in two places and not just one ?

1. **WordPress Address (URL) / WP_SITEURL:** The address where your
   WordPress core files reside.
2. **Site Address (URL) / WP_HOME:** The address typed in a browser to
   reach your WordPress blog.

[image: WordPress Settings SSL]

You mentioned in comment below the question that you face issue in updating the URL via dashboard. The reason may be that you might have hard coded the URL in config.php which overrides the dashboard settings which comes from db values.

> Hard coding values of URL settings in the wp-config.php file makes you
> lose the ability to modify them from the dashboard.

So, now if the above statement is true then proceed changing the values in config.php as follows

1. Edit your **wp-config.php** file.
2. Define your **WP_HOME** and **WP_SITEURL** settings by inserting these lines
   towards the top:

> ```
> define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
>
> define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
> ```

In case if its already perfect then try changing these two values in db as follows

Navigate to  **wp_options** table in phpmyadmin

> Your wp_ prefix may differ depending on your installation settings.

Click edit beside either the **siteurl** or **home** entries.

You may need to search for them with the Filter rows function at the top.

[image]

Enter in your new value in the **option_value** field, then click Go

[image]

Comment: Changing the two URLs in the wp-config.php file worked for me. Thank you very much!